# With JJB (Jenkins Job Builder) is it possible to set environment variables without making them a job parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-builder

I'd like to set a bunch of variables to be used inside JJB-created `pipeline-scm` job scripts, e.g. details about CI infrastructure.

It's possible to set those variables using `parameters`:

```yaml
- job:
    name: "some-job"
    project-type: pipeline
    pipeline-scm:
      ...
    parameters:
      - string:
          name: NODE
          default: "{node}"
```

`NODE` can now be used inside a Groovy-Script like this:

```java
node(env.NODE) {
   stage('Checkout') {
   ...
   }
   stage(..){..}
}
```

But now `NODE` is a job parameter which on the one hand can be changed (which I don't want) and it's being shown next to job parameters I *want* to be visible and changeable.

Is there a way to just define environment variables for a Jenkins job (like folder properties, i.e. not visible on the "Build with properties" page)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [envinject](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) plugin and define the environment variables as properties-content

```yaml
- job:
    properties:
      - inject:
          properties-content: "NODE={node}"
```